# Cyrillic in minted label

Tags: minted, sourcecode, cyrillic

Is it posible to use the Cyrillic text for the `label` option in minted source code listing?

I try to compile this piece of latex code with xelatex:

```
\begin{minted}[mathescape,frame=lines,label=Паралелепіпед]{c++}
G4Box(const G4String& pName, // Ім'я об'єкту
               G4double  pX, // Напівдовжина за X
               G4double  pY, // Напівдовжина за Y
               G4double  pZ) // Напівдовжина за Z
\end{minted}
```

Comment: @egreg This is not about the '\label', but about the 'label' option of the minted environment. And I use XeLaTeX by the way.

Comment: I see; the error I get is `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)` which seems to mean that the label can be only ASCII. :(

Comment: This may be due to terminal encoding and/or a Pygments bug under Python 2.  See [this](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/11) for some possible solutions/workarounds.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is no issue in recent versions of Pygments and minted anymore.